# Getting current user home directory on OS X?

Tags: python, macos, home-directory

How to find current user home directory on OS X?

`HOME` environmental variable is not always set, for example when you do not run in console (GUI apps).

For this reason I'm looking for a generic solution, one that will fall-back if `os.environ['HOME']` is not set.

There is a [similar question (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020187/getting-home-directory-in-mac-os-x-using-c-language) but it already has an accepted solution that is invalid.

A Python solution would be preferred but other languages are welcome as long they provide a valid home or at least one location where you can write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that `os.path.expanduser("~")` always returns the home directory, even on Windows.